# Prove $\lim_{x \to c}{x^2}=c^2$ where $c$ is a real number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove $\lim_{x \to c}{x^2}=c^2$ where $c$ is a real number with the $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition. I know that you need to assume a value for $\delta$. However, I don't understand how that one assumption, which only represents one case, implies that the limit is always true. Please explain as you prove the limit.

Comment: What does the definition of continuity say?

Comment: Given an $\epsilon>0$ you need to provide a corresponding $\delta>0$... and then show it works.  It usually helps to work backwards.

Comment: $\delta$ can be chosen in terms of $\epsilon$, which is why the proof goes through in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $|x^2 - c^2| = |(x+c)(x-c)|=|x+c||x-c|<|x+c|\cdot \delta \leq (|x|+|c|) \cdot \delta$

Why is $|x-c|<\delta$?

You have control to make $|x-c|<\delta$ as small as you like, can you see how to do this so you get control of how big $|x|$ can be ?

Think about for instance $|x-c|<1 \leq \delta$.